# Altium hatched polygon not covering whole PCB on one layer

Tags: pcb, altium, pcb-layers, polygon

I have a two layer PCB on which I want to use hatched polygons on top and bottom layers. For some reason the hatched GND polygon on the bottom layer is not covering the whole layer.

*PCB Layout*
[image: PCB Layout]

*Bottom layer polygon properties*
[image: Bottom Layer Polygon properties]

On both layer I have a keep out zone.

What am I missing? The top layer polygon is perfect, and the bottom layer polygon has the same properties.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by adding the keep out zones first and then make a new polygon pour not covering the whole PCB but following the lines of the keep out zone.

[image]

Comment: This link will take you to an excellent (and official) Altium resource: forum.live.altium.com